# Sanity check: self-homeomorphisms of a punctured torus is discrete?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I know that the self homeomorphisms of a closed torus is disconnected, with connected component the group of translations, and component group the mapping class group, isomorphic to $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ (here everything is oriented/orientation-preserving). The self-homeomorphisms of a punctured torus should correspond to the self-homeomorphisms of the closed torus which fix the origin. By lifting to universal covers, any such self-homeomorphism lifts to an $\mathbb{R}$-linear self map of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which stabilizes the lattice, and hence again must be an element of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$.

Assuming that restriction gives a bijection between the group of self-homeomorphisms of a torus fixing the origin with the group of self-homeomorphisms of the torus with the origin removed, this seems to suggest that the group of self-homeomorphisms of a punctured torus is discrete and isomorphic to $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$. Is this correct?

If this is not true, can someone give an example of a nontrivial homeomorphism of the punctured torus which is homotopic to the identity?

Comment: How do you know automorphisms of the punctured torus correspond to automorphisms fixing the basepoint of the torus? This isn't true generally for manifolds. Remove the origin from the open 2-disk and then reflect each point across the circle of radius $1/2$. This is a homeomorphism, but clearly does not extend to a homeomorphism of the open disk fixing the origin..

Comment: Actually, I 100% believe it for all compact manifolds.

Comment: @ConnorMalin That's an interesting example, but the map you describe is orientation reversing. Here's the argument that I was imagining: Take a sequence in the punctured torus $T^*$ whose limit in the compact torus $T$ is the origin. If $f$ is a self-homeomorphism of $T^*$ then the image of the sequence under $f$ cannot have a limit point (otherwise $f^{-1}$ would not be defined). Thus $f$ must send any nonconverging Cauchy sequences in $T^*$ to another such nonconverging sequence. This should imply that $f$ induces a map on $T$, viewed as the metric completion of $T^*$.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Actually if I'm right, then the relevant reason that your example is different is probably because I'm guessing there is no metric on the open punctured disk realizing it as the complement of a single point of its metric completion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conclusion isn't true. Here is an example of a map homotopic to the identity:

Pick a disk around the punctured point and declare the map outside this disk to be the identity. Pick a chart so this is the unit disk. Then define the map inside the disk to rotate the points by $1-r$ where r is the distance to the origin.

A homotopy to the identity is given by $H(x,t)$ is the identity if $x$ is outside the disk and $H(x,t)$ rotates the points by $(1-t)(1-r)$.

I think the issue with your reasoning is your statement that it is $\mathbb{R}$-linear and stabilize the lattice. I can't see any reason either of these would be true.

Comment: Ok, I see why it should stabilize the lattice, but not the linearity.

Comment: Does your map also extend to a continuous map of the closed torus? (Intuitively perhaps the hypothetical extension to the puncture should not be continuous there, but I can't convince myself of it)

Comment: Yes it does because when you rotate around the origin you stay close to the origin.

Comment: This is confusing. I was under the impression that the homeomorphisms of the closed torus isotopic to the identity consisted only of translations.

Comment: That impression is false, as the example in this answer shows.